# PayPal failed to set preapproval payment when I turn the app to the live mode

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal Preapproved payments for my funding website, where people come to support kids living in a challenging environment. The payment system works fine on the sandbox account, but when changed to the live mode with the live account gives this message to the client **" Sorry, we were not able to set up preapproved payments at this time. please return to the merchant and choose another way to pay"**, this appears to all clients who want to donate, and also it forces the user to subscribe to the PayPal if they choose to pay with the MasterCard without having a PayPal account. Bellow is my code:

Here I'm creating access token

````
    include_once("cleansheet.php");

    //keys and ids
    $live_client_id="****";
    $sand_client_id="****";
    $live_secrete_key="****";
    $sand_secrete_key="****";
    $sand_request_uri="api-m.sandbox";
    $live_request_uri="api-m";

    if(isset($_POST["donate_to"])){
        $amount=clear_num($_POST["amount"]);
        $biling_cycle=clear_data($_POST["radio"]);
        $donate_to=clear_data($_POST["donate_to"]);
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$live_request_uri.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$live_client_id.':'.$live_secrete_key);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en_US';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $err=curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        
        
        if($err){header("Location:error"); exit();}
        else{
            $response=json_decode($result);
            if($response-> access_token){$access_token=$response-> access_token; header("location:./create_product?token=$access_token&cycle=$biling_cycle&donateto=$donate_to&amount=$amount"); exit();}
            else{header("Location:error"); exit();}
        }
    }
?>```

Here I'm creating the product

    ```<?php 
    
        include_once("cleansheet.php");
        $token=$_GET["token"];
        $amount=clear_num($_GET["amount"]);
        $biling_cycle=clear_data($_GET["cycle"]);
        $donate_to=clear_data($_GET["donateto"]);
        $unique_id=md5(uniqid());
        $ch = curl_init();
    
        $sand_request_uri="api-m.sandbox";
        $live_request_uri="api-m";
    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$live_request_uri.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"name\": \"$donate_to\",\n  \"description\": \"We value your donation\",\n  \"type\": \"SERVICE\",\n  \"category\": \"SOFTWARE\",\n  \"image_url\": \"https://example.com/streaming.jpg\",\n  \"home_url\": \"https://example.com/home\"\n}");
    
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.rawurlencode($token);
        $headers[] = 'Paypal-Request-Id: '.rawurldecode($unique_id);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $err=curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    
        if ($err) {header("Location:error"); exit();}
        else{
            $response=json_decode($result);
            if($response->id){$product_id=$response->id; header("location:create_plan?pid=$product_id&token=$token&amount=$amount&cycle=$biling_cycle&donateto=$donate_to"); exit();}
            else{header("Location:error"); exit();}
        }
    ?>```

Then here I'm creating a plan

    ```<?php 
    
        include_once("cleansheet.php");
        $token=$_GET["token"];
        $amount=clear_num($_GET["amount"]);
        $biling_cycle=clear_data($_GET["cycle"]);
        $donate_to=clear_data($_GET["donateto"]);
        if($biling_cycle=="monthly"){$circle_v=0;$auto_standing=true;}else{$circle_v=1;$auto_standing='false';}
    
        $pid=$_GET["pid"];
        $plan_id=md5(uniqid());
        $ch = curl_init();
    
        $sand_request_uri="api-m.sandbox";
        $live_request_uri="api-m";
    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$live_request_uri.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\"product_id\": \"$pid\",
            \n\"name\":\"$donate_to\",\n\"description\":\"We value your donation\",
            \n\"billing_cycles\": [\n\n{\n\"frequency\": {\n\"interval_unit\":\"MONTH\",\n\"interval_count\": 1\n},
            \n\"tenure_type\":\"REGULAR\",\n\"sequence\":1,\n\"total_cycles\":$circle_v,\n\"pricing_scheme\":{\n\"fixed_price\": {\n\"value\":\"$amount\",
            \n\"currency_code\":\"USD\"\n}\n}\n}\n],\n\"`payment_preferences`\": {\n\"auto_bill_outstanding\":$auto_standing,\n\"setup_fee\": {\n\"value\": \"0\",\n\"currency_code\": \"USD\"\n},
            \n\"setup_fee_failure_action\": \"CONTINUE\",\n\"payment_failure_threshold\": 3\n},\n\"taxes\": {\n\"percentage\": \"0\",\n\"inclusive\": false\n}\n}");
    
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.rawurlencode($token);
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Paypal-Request-Id: '.rawurlencode($plan_id);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $err=curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    
        if ($err) {header("Location:error"); exit();}
        else{
            $response=json_decode($result);
            if($response->id){$plan_id=$response->id;header("location:pay?plan_id=$plan_id&token=$token&amount=$amount&cycle=$biling_cycle&donateto=$donate_to"); exit();}
            else{header("Location:error"); exit();}
        }
    ?>```

Here client pay

    ```<?php 
    
        include_once("cleansheet.php");
        $token=$_GET["token"];
        $amount=clear_num($_GET["amount"]);
        $biling_cycle=clear_data($_GET["cycle"]);
        $donate_to=clear_data($_GET["donateto"]);
        $plan_id=$_GET["plan_id"];
    
        $live_client_id="**";
        $sand_client_id="**";
        $live_secrete_key="***";
        $sand_secrete_key="***";
        $sand_request_uri="api-m.sandbox";
        $live_request_uri="api-m";
    
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="#" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="CodePen">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" />
        <link rel="mask-icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" color="#111" />
        <title>DONATE</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inter-ui/3.19.3/inter.css'>
        <style>section {font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;}</style>
        <script>window.console = window.console || function(t) {};</script>
        <script>if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");} </script>
        <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<?php echo $live_client_id; ?>&vault=true&intent=subscription"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body translate="no" >
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss-jit-cdn"></script>
        <script type="tailwind-config">
            {
                theme: {
                    extend: {
                        colors: {
                            gray: colors.blueGray,
                            pink: colors.fuchsia,  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    
        <!-- Snippet -->
        <section class="flex flex-col justify-center antialiased bg-gray-200 text-gray-600 min-h-screen p-4">
            <div class="h-full">
                <div class="max-w-[360px] mx-auto">
                    <div class="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg mt-9">
                        <header class="text-center px-5 pb-5" style='padding:20px;'>
                            <h3 class="text-xl font-bold text-gray-900 mb-1">KIDOGOKIDOGO.ORG</h3>
                        </header>
                        <div class="bg-gray-100 text-center px-5 py-6">
                            <div class="text-sm mb-6"><strong class="font-semibold">Donate $<?php echo $amount; ?></strong></div>
                            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
      
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.7.0/cdn.js'></script>
        <script>
            var token='<?php echo $token; ?>';
            var planid='<?php echo $plan_id; ?>';
            var cycle='<?php echo $biling_cycle; ?>';
    
            paypal.Buttons({
                createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
                    return actions.subscription.create({'plan_id': '<?php echo $plan_id; ?>'});
                },
                onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                    alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
                    window.location=`sub_details?sub_id=${data.subscriptionID}&token=${token}&cycle=${cycle}`;
                }
            }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Renders the PayPal button
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>```

Its about 3 days of try and error, but I am still stuck. is there anyone who can help?
````

Comment: Add an example of the rendered page for when the button is shown for the client to click and pay. (Rendered means the HTML output that is served and loaded in the browser, no PHP nor variables at this point)

Comment: Thank you, @PrestonPHX, for showing cooperation. The last code on the list gives the users a page where they click the button to pay. It shows the amount and two payment methods, credit card and PayPal option

Comment: Yes, I know what it does. Please add its HTML here so we can review the result and problem you're having.

Comment: Do you mean the first page, which leads to the whole process? Because the last code has its HTML docs

Comment: No, the HTML source of the last page ("Here client pay"). The one with the yellow PayPal button and generated live plan_id that opens the window when clicked and results in the error.

Comment: It is available there, @PrestonPHX, right after the end tag of PHP on ("Here client pay"). There is HTML code to render the button for triggering the PayPal payment window. (Below the end tag of PHP)